# Anyone with a live example of Facebook's <fb:comments-count href=http://example.com/></fb:comments-count> awesome comments?

Tags: facebook, comments

The Facebook comments-count tag doesn't seem to work for me.

```
<fb:comments-count href=http://example.com/></fb:comments-count> awesome comments
```

Should I use fb.event.subscribe() to keep track of new comments and sum the count?

Thanks,

Comment: I can relate to your question... facebook documentation sucks - I don't think many people can actually find their arms and legs there...

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must change http://example.com to your url.

Then I got the same problem as you. I managed to figure it out... I think you are missing this code snippet:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
```

Put this code in the end of your  tag. And Viola, it should work!

If you still have some problems, use this code snippet

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?href=example.com&permalink=1" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:130px; height:16px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

instead of

```
<fb:comments-count href=http://example.com/></fb:comments-count> awesome comments
```